# Jquery UI Issue with slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4nnfzz5a/6/

When you click yes on 3, 4 moves down then comes back up. It looks like there is some CSS being added to `#q2`

Comment: We're not supposed to write JavaScript and CSS that way. Learn why and when should you use CSS classes, and how to use functions in JavaScript. Imagine one day you wanted to have 100 questions... you would copy-paste your JS logic 100 times? And you would do up to `#q100{ text-align: center;}`? Or simply use `.panel{text-align:center}`...

Comment: (offtopic) What's the purpose of the *back* button? Styling the selected answers would be also fine... Why every NO button hops that red alert?.. The UI makes no sense overall.

Comment: Also, what's `< Back </span> 4` ? you mean `&lt; Back </span> 4`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan these are requirements I got from my client, this is what they wanted so I did it. If you can help me with my issue I would appreciate it. I am not sure how your comments help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add multiple event handler you can do that with single handler. Used [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) & [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to show/hide panel.

```js
$(".panel-body input[type='radio']").change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
    $(this).parents('.panel').hide();
    $(this).parents('.panel').next().show("slide", {
      direction: "right"
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('#alert').show("slide", {
      direction: "up"
    }, 500);
  }
});

$(".panel-heading .back").click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.panel').hide();
  $(this).parents('.panel').prev().show("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#q1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#q2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#q3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#q4 {
  text-align: center;
}

#q5 {
  text-align: center;
}

.unsure {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.unsure a {
  color: #1e5973;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#texta {
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

#q5cdq {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.back {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.q5cdqa {
  text-align: left;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#q5faq {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#q5faq a {
  color: #1e5973;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#q5n a {
  color: #1e5973;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#q5wct a {
  color: #1e5973;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#q5ilt a {
  color: #1e5973;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div#q5wct {
  font-size: 18px;
}

div#q5ilt {
  font-size: 18px;
}

p.cdq img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

p.no img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

p.faq img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

p.wct img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

p.ilt img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

p.no {
  font-size: 30px;
}

p.faq {
  font-size: 30px;
}

p.cdq {
  font-size: 30px;
}

p.cdq:hover {
  color: #1e5973;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p.no:hover {
  color: #1e5973;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p.faq:hover {
  color: #1e5973;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p.wct:hover {
  color: #1e5973;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p.ilt:hover {
  color: #1e5973;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#checkbox {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

label {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

label>input {
  /* HIDE RADIO */
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Makes input not-clickable */
  position: absolute;
  /* Remove input from document flow */
}

label>input+img {
  /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

label>input:checked+img {
  /* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}

.lightbox_title {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #1e5973;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.panel-default {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #64656a;
  background-color: #c2cdd2;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.panel-body {
  background-color: #42afdf;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.questions {
  font-family: Nunito;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.alert-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

#logo {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Start Red Alert-->
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger exit" role="alert" style="display:none;">
  <span>NIH does <b>not</b> consider your study to be a clinical trial.<span><br /><br />Make sure you select a funding opportunity announcement (FOA) that is NOT specifically for clinical trials.
 </div>
<!-- End Red Alert--> 



<!-- Start Question 1--> 
 <div id="q1" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="questions">
    <p class="unsure">1</p>
    <div id="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="yes" />YES
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="no"/>NO
        </label>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Question 1-->

<!--Question 2-->
<div id="q2" class="panel panel-default" style="display:none;">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="back">< Back </span> 2</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="questions">
    <p class="unsure">2</p>
    <div id="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="yes" />YES
        </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="no"/>NO
        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End Question 2-->



<!--Question 3-->
<div id="q3" class="panel panel-default" style="display:none;">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="back">< Back </span> 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="questions">
      <p class="unsure">3</p>
      <div id="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="yes" />YES
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="no"/>NO
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Question 3-->


<!--Question 4-->
<div id="q4" class="panel panel-default" style="display:none;">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="back">< Back </span> 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="questions">
      <p class="unsure">4</p>
      <div id="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="yes" />YES
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="no"/>NO
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Question 4-->


<!--Question 5-->
<div id="q5" class="panel panel-default" style="display:none;">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="back">< Back </span> 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="questions">
      <p class="unsure">5</p>
      <div id="checkbox">
        DONE DONE GO BACK
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Question 5-->
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than what I did. Thank you, this is working properly for me. I guess my event handlers were confused.